# How to logging aerospike query using spring-data-aerospike

Tags: logging, spring-data, aerospike

How to logging aerospike query using spring data crudrepository?
Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presently there is no logging output in Spring Data Aerospike CrudRepositories. The Java client logs are registered [here](https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike/blob/2.4.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/aerospike/core/BaseAerospikeTemplate.java#L90).